# Three data sets in one plot in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

The goal is to plot three data sets in one plot:
(DATE1_GOOD, DATE1_BAD);
(DATE2_GOOD, DATE2_BAD);
(DATE3_GOOD, DATE3_BAD).
Unfortunately, I'm getting all possible combinations:
[image]

So now the task is to combine the three diagonal plots into one and delete the rest since they make no sense. I tried dragging the axes but the result is not what I'm looking for, I get:
(DATE3_GOOD, DATE1_BAD);
(DATE3_GOOD, DATE2_BAD);
(DATE3_GOOD, DATE3_BAD):
[image]

I'm new to Tableau, is it even possible to do what I want?

Comment: One possibility is to create three new fields (possibly as user defined functions or,easier, by reformatting the raw data in the DB or in tableau prep). one containing all `date good` values, one containing all the `date bad` values and a third classifying each row into date1, date2 and date3. plot `date good` vs `date bad` on a single plot and then drag the class field (date1 etc) onto colour.

Comment: Great idea. Thanks! My problem is solved.